# What is the difference between ":=" and ".=" assignment in BitBake?

Tags: bitbake

I saw in a [BitBake](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake) .conf file:

```
BBPATH := "${TOPDIR}"
```

and

```
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
```

What is the difference between `:=` and `.=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [BitBake manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#immediate-variable-expansion):

> The `:=` operator results in a variable's contents being expanded immediately.
> If you want to append or prepend values without an inserted space, use the `.=` and `=.` operators.

Comment: yeap. that was correct. It was a domain-specific-language for bitbake. (appending assignemtn ) https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#appending-and-prepending-without-spaces

Answer (score 2):

As people have pointed out, a Bitbake config file does NOT use regular (i.e. sh, csh, bash, ksh, etc) shell script syntax.  Bitbake has its own config language.  (It is described as "similar to several other languages", but the differences are large enough that you cannot infer Bitbake semantics from (say) Bash.)

For more info, read the Bitbake User Manual.  The relevant section is [Section 3.1 - Basic Syntax](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#basic-syntax).

It explains that:

- `:=` performs an immediate (i.e. at config parse time) variable expansion on the right hand side.  By contrast, with `=`, the variable expansion is deferred until the variable on the left hand side is used.
- `.=` performs an append without a space between the existing and appended value.  This is also done immediately.